# Positioning QHBoxLayout vertically

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am in the early stages of learning PYQT and have ran into of problem with creating a layout I have in mind.

I want to create a layout for a login screen which looks like the following:

[image: login screen]

- I have tried using a GridLayout to get the desired look
- Have also tried setting buddy to username/textfield and password/textfield then putting everything in a HBox then nesting it inside of a VBox which I thought would work but it didnt.

I have looked online and have found out about the use of relative layouts which I think might be the best way to achieve this layout but cant find out the syntax for it. ANy help would be appreciated

EDIT:

So, I have managed to get the desired layout by creating 3 HBoxes:

- one containing the username label and textfield
- A second to store the password label and textfield
- The third to store the push button.

I have then placed them all inside a VBoxLayout. Is this an okay way of achieving this or or there a better way of going about it?

Comment: Nested H/VBoxLayouts is a fine way to get rows or columns which are not really a grid.

Comment: Have you looked at [QFormLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qformlayout.html)?